# How to get SafariLauncher to launch Safari on real iPhone

Tags: java, ios, selenium, safari, appium

Long story short, I followed this http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/ios.html?java# tutorial and now I have a project. Unfortunately, I cannot find a tutorial for running appium with a web page. So far, I have edited to fit my needs, i.e. let's say it brings up google.com, which works in the emulator.

I have installed SafariLauncher on the device. When manually clicking the app it DOES work.

However, when I use SafariLauncher and appium as you can tell it does not work.

Here is what the console is telling me ->

```
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 5343fa7f9c04cb60f02cb40f1233073d23dbbbc7
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 5343fa7f9c04cb60f02cb40f1233073d23dbbbc7 /Users/wroberts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-fvxpuhbhozeuydcsrdzjhhzlzpsu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SafariLauncher.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/wroberts/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-971fed56c9389ee5.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-11-21 15:09:18.206 instruments[19158:3c0b] Error fetching kdebug events
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Users/wroberts/dev/differnt_svns/mobile_automation/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:387:31)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/wroberts/dev/differnt_svns/mobile_au`enter code here`tomation/appium/submodules/appium-  instruments/lib/instruments.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
```

and here is my relevant code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.3.1");

    //capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");

    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");

    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Tahir's iPhone");

    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "5343fa7f9c04cb60f02cb40f1233073d23dbbbc7");

    String bundle = "/Users/wroberts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SafariLauncher-fvxpuhbhozeuydcsrdzjhhzlzpsu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SafariLauncher.app";

    capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", bundle);


    capabilities.setCapability("app", bundle);


    driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);    

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(20000);
```

So in short, can ANYONE get SafariLauncher to work on a real device?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the browser name capability if you want to run tests with the Safari browser:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.3.1");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Tahir's iPhone");
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "your_udid");
capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", bundle);
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "safari");
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);    

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
Thread.sleep(20000);
```

and you don't need the other SafariLaucher settings if you just want to use the Safari browser on a real phone.

This SafariTest example code from Saucelabs shows just that:

https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/java/junit/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/appium/SafariTest.java

Comment: That is for the simulator, not a real device.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that maybe you don't need the SafariLauncher at all. The example is for the Simulator, but you can do the same for real device. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use XCUITest to start Safari instead of SafariLauncher

1. Necessary installed software

   Two pieces of software are currently necessary to run iOS tests on real devices:

   - `libimobiledevice` - install using `brew install libimobiledevice
     --HEAD`
   - `ios-deploy` - install using `npm install -g ios-deploy`
2. Setting up WebDriverAgentRunner on real device as [document](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md#full-manual-configuration)
3. Add desired capabilities config as below in source code:

> ```
> platformName: "iOS",
> platformVersion: "10.3",
> deviceName: "HCiPhone",
> browserName: "safari",
> udid: "5343fa7f9c04cb60f02cb40f1233073d23dbbbc7",
> startIWDP: true,
> safariInitialUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com/"
> ```